# Azure AD B2C Twitter Idp is not working

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have custom signIn/SignUp policy with Different social Idp's configured and Twitter is one of them. It was working until last month and now we are getting this error as soon as we click on Twitter. There was no changes done in our configuration

```
Whoa there!

There is no request token for this page. That's the special key we need from applications asking to use your Twitter account. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a mistake.
```

Is anyone having this issue?

Please help

Thanks,

Comment: Is it affected by this developer announcement: https://twittercommunity.com/t/action-required-sign-in-with-twitter-users-must-whitelist-callback-urls/105342?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, This seems to be a common issue when Twitter makes an update or has an outage. The problem seems to go away after Twitter resolves the issue.

Otherwise some possibilities are:

1. You might be using OAuth2, while Twitter uses OAuth
2. Ensure that 'Enable Callback Locking' is not ticked in the application settings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

Following the solution posted in this link solved the problem

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureadb2c/2018/06/13/twitter-login-changes-to-signin-handshake-fix/